# Does Komodo Edit list variables?

Tags: perl, komodo, komodoedit

I'm using Komodo Edit as an IDE for PERL.  Is there a way to show all the declared variables on the side panel?  I know it keeps track of it since there is a red wiggly line if I use a variable that has not been previously declared - would be nice if there was a list somewhere. Plugins would be cool too but I can't seem to find any.  thanks in advance! 
Ahdee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is **not possible in Komodo Edit**. [See the comparrisson page](http://komodoide.com/komodo-edit/) for the additional features the IDE has that Edit doesn't have. The one you want here is called *Code Browser*.

In Komodo IDE however, it is: It is called *Code Explorer* and you can move it between the left and right panel. You get it by clicking the button which is blue in my screenshot abouve the `Text-2.txt` file tab, as it starts out being on the right.

Note that it does not recognize methods introduced by Moo(se) or variables that are imported through `use`.

[image: Komodo IDE screenshot]

Comment: thanks this solves it... to bad perhaps I can find a free plugin somewhere.